# Can't display my activity from navigation drawer

Tags: android, drawer

I have a navigation drawer with some options (Home, Bluetooth, Alarm, Tips). I linked an activity to Bluetooth and Alarm but I got some problems with Home. 
When I run the application I have a splash screen which is connected to the Home.java, in this activity I can click on my drawer and select the others alarm.java anche bluetooth.java but, when I link an activity to home, using the same method, my app stops working.
Thank you so much!

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.progetto.app">

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Home"
            android:label="@string/Home"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Alarm"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_alarm"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Bluetooth"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_bt"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Tips"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_tips"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        <activity android:name=".AlarmActivity" />
        <receiver android:name=".Alarm_Receiver" />
        <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".ArduinoMain"/>


        <service
            android:name=".RingtonePlayingService"
            android:enabled="true" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Home.java with drawer navigation

```
    package com.progetto.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    DrawerLayout drawer;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    Toolbar toolbar = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (id){

            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent h = new Intent(Home.this,ArduinoMain.class);
                startActivity(h);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_bt:
                Intent i = new Intent(Home.this,DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_alarm:
                Intent g = new Intent(Home.this,AlarmActivity.class);
                startActivity(g);
                break;

            case R.id.nav_tips:
                Intent s = new Intent(Home.this,Tips.class);
                startActivity(s);
                break;

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }


}
```

This is the activity I'm trying to connect to Home, I want to see this activity when the spash screen is over

```
    package com.progetto.app;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ArduinoMain extends Activity {

    //Declare buttons & editText
    Button functionOne, functionTwo;

    private EditText editText;

    //Memeber Fields
    private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = null;
    private BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    private OutputStream outStream = null;

    // UUID service - This is the type of Bluetooth device that the BT module is
    // It is very likely yours will be the same, if not google UUID for your manufacturer
    private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    // MAC-address of Bluetooth module
    public String newAddress = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arduino_main);

        addKeyListener();

        //Initialising buttons in the view
        //mDetect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mDetect);
        functionOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.functionOne);
        functionTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.functionTwo);

        //getting the bluetooth adapter value and calling checkBTstate function
        btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        checkBTState();

        /**************************************************************************************************************************8
         *  Buttons are set up with onclick listeners so when pressed a method is called
         *  In this case send data is called with a value and a toast is made
         *  to give visual feedback of the selection made
         */

        functionOne.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendData("1");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Function 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        functionTwo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendData("2");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Function 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // connection methods are best here in case program goes into the background etc

        //Get MAC address from DeviceListActivity
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        newAddress = intent.getStringExtra(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);

        // Set up a pointer to the remote device using its address.
        BluetoothDevice device = btAdapter.getRemoteDevice(newAddress);

        //Attempt to create a bluetooth socket for comms
        try {
            btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR - Could not create Bluetooth socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Establish the connection.
        try {
            btSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            try {
                btSocket.close();        //If IO exception occurs attempt to close socket
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR - Could not close Bluetooth socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        // Create a data stream so we can talk to the device
        try {
            outStream = btSocket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR - Could not create bluetooth outstream", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        //When activity is resumed, attempt to send a piece of junk data ('x') so that it will fail if not connected
        // i.e don't wait for a user to press button to recognise connection failure
        sendData("x");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Pausing can be the end of an app if the device kills it or the user doesn't open it again
        //close all connections so resources are not wasted

        //Close BT socket to device
        try     {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e2) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR - Failed to close Bluetooth socket", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    //takes the UUID and creates a comms socket
    private BluetoothSocket createBluetoothSocket(BluetoothDevice device) throws IOException {

        return  device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
    }

    //same as in device list activity
    private void checkBTState() {
        // Check device has Bluetooth and that it is turned on
        if(btAdapter==null) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR - Device does not support bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        } else {
            if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            } else {
                //Prompt user to turn on Bluetooth
                Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 1);
            }
        }
    }

    // Method to send data
    private void sendData(String message) {
        byte[] msgBuffer = message.getBytes();

        try {
            //attempt to place data on the outstream to the BT device
            outStream.write(msgBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if the sending fails this is most likely because device is no longer there
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ERROR - Device not found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
    }
    public void addKeyListener() {

        // get edittext component
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        // add a keylistener to keep track user input
        editText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                // if keydown and send is pressed implement the sendData method
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                    //I have put the * in automatically so it is no longer needed when entering text
                    sendData('*' + editText.getText().toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sending text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is the splash screen

```
    package com.progetto.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

        private ImageView iv;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
            iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv);
            Animation myanim= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.mytransition);
            iv.startAnimation(myanim);


            final Intent i=new Intent(this, Home.class);
            Thread timer =new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    finally{
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            timer.start();
        }
    }
```

This is the project
[DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/muhje7ucwewadoj/App%20-%20Copia.rar?dl=0)

This is the apk
[Apk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibrf3mpdqia09a7/apk.rar?dl=0)

Comment: Please post the error logs

Comment: Where is it? I have no error when I compile

Comment: Not error while compiling. When the app crashes, you'll find errors in Logcat tab at the bottom if you are using Android Studio.

Comment: My adb doesn't work unfortunatly, I'm using my phone

Comment: You can connect your phone to your system. And select your mobile in the Logcat.